# How do I develop applications for Symbian OS of Mobile Phones like Nokia

Tags: symbian, nokia, mobile-phones

I would like to develop applications for Symbian OS Phones and try another track other than programming in Java. I would like to experience how to program on mobile phones using C and C++.

Can you please give some tips on what tools to use on developing this kinds of applications. I am targetting Nokia phones..

Answer (score 10):

Now that the Carbide IDE is all free, the main differences between amateur versus professional Symbian OS development are:
- use of free development certificates to sign your application, as opposed to paying verisign and a test house to identify and verify your application.
- use of free GCCE compiler instead of the more optimised RVCT.

forum nokia is definitely a great resource.
I would also suggest http://developer.symbian.org and http://www.newlc.com

Shameless plug: the latest book to learn about Symbian OS native C++ development is at
http://www.quickrecipesonsymbianos.com

Answer (score 4):

There are two options for you:

- Symbian C++: follow the instruction from link http://www.developer.nokia.com/Develop/Other_Technologies/Symbian_C++/
- Qt C++/QML: detail instructions are found at
  http://www.developer.nokia.com/Develop/Qt/Getting_started/

Qt C++/QML is preferable for latest Symbian platform application development.

Answer (score 2):

Qt c++ is the best choice. I saw many mobile application developers are developing applications with Qt C++. So I recommend to go with Qt C++.